# When I try to install git I get this error

Tags: dpkg, matlab

When I try to install git I get this error:

```
$ sudo apt install git
[sudo] password for nitk: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
git is already the newest version (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.3).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.10.0-28 linux-headers-4.10.0-28-generic
  linux-headers-4.10.0-37 linux-headers-4.10.0-37-generic
  linux-image-4.10.0-28-generic linux-image-4.10.0-37-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-28-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-37-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 299 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up matlab-support (0.0.21) ...
No default Matlab path found. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package matlab-support (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of matlab-gdf:
 matlab-gdf depends on matlab-support; however:
  Package matlab-support is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package matlab-gdf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 matlab-support
 matlab-gdf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) and modify your query.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not have Matlab installed or the path to it is unknown.

If you don't need Matlab or Matlab-support try running:

```
apt-get remove matlab-support
```

If you do need Matlab and Matlab-support try running:

```
apt-get install matlab-support
```

and provide the full path to your Matlab install.